# How to force reformat file with black code formatter

Tags: python, code-formatting, python-black, black-code-formatter

I have a file in a git repo that is not reformatted for reason `wasn't modified on disk since last run.`
But eventually, a change is made in the file e.g new line. And a whole lot of major reformatting is done by black.
The file seems to have pending reformatting work which is not detected because it hasn't been modified.

How do I force black to reformat/check a file regardless of whether it has been modified since last run?

Comment: you can just run `black your_file_name.py`

Comment: I solved my issue. It was a version issue. local black v19.10 was ignoring the files but CI black was on latest v20 and was reformatting the files.

Comment: So I made the wrong assumption that a force reformat was needed.